# Price validation includes word "Free" if users put 0 or words in price field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do i make it so if users put the number **0** or type any words in my price:decimal field it registers it as the word **Free**?

As of now i just validate presence of price:

```
validates :price,      :presence => true
```

Comment: you can do it on the fly with javascript.

Comment: @Mikhail Nikalyukin could you point me in the right direction to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would have your field reference a new pair of get/set methods for "price_string"

```
#in your model
def price_string
  price == 0 ? "Free" : price
end

def price_string=(string)
  price = (string == "free" ? 0 : string)
end
```

Now you can refer to "price_string" in your forms.

```
#in your form
f.text_field :price_string
```

Comment: i tried typing in my price_string field "wdwds" or 0 and got back error "Price can't be blank". Edit: I even tried a legit price and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to add a before_validation callback to do it.

```
class ModelWithPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  # your validations ...

  before_validation :convert_price_to_number

private
  def convert_price_to_number
     # no need to check for strings, to_f return 0.0 if the value cant be converted
     self.price = self.price.to_f

     # convert 0 to "Free" if needed
     self.price = "Free" if self.price == 0
  end
end
```

Comment: What exactly is the covert_price_to_number doing?

Comment: it call to_f (convert to float) in the price attribute. If the price is a string which can not be converted to float, like "free", it will return 0.0

Comment: OK, but does this also make the word "Free" be put into there if they type an invalid price?

Comment: sorry i forgot that part, i fixed the answer to reflect the change.

Comment: @Pablo Castellazzi Well, i put down the following code and still no luck, I'm going to show you my Price Model ( by editing the original question) and if you want to see anything else let me know. thanks for the support!

Comment: @Pablo Castellazzi, its actually a decimal, could that have been the issue?

Comment: If you want to keep it that way you need to create a value object and register it with [composed_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Aggregations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-composed_of). For the value object class you may create a derived class from Float and override to_s.